# How do I get the RGB values from an image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a mobile client for my object-detection server. I already have a perfectly-working python client which takes an image as input, sends it to the server in an HTTP request and receives prediction as a json response. I'm trying to achieve the same in Dart which I'm fairly new to.

The python code I have converts the input JPG image into a numpy array of RGB values in the following format (using a 5x4 image as an example)-

```
[
[[182, 171, 153], [203, 188, 169], [242, 214, 200], [255, 235, 219], [155, 111, 98]],
[[181, 171, 146], [204, 190, 164], [255, 237, 214], [177, 142, 120], [84, 42, 20]], 
[[176, 168, 129], [218, 206, 166], [180, 156, 118], [91, 59, 21], [103, 64, 25]],
[[186, 180, 132], [166, 156, 107], [91, 68, 24], [94, 63, 17], [122, 84, 39]]
]
```

In my dart code, I have attempted to convert the image into a list of 8-bit unsigned integers using-

```
Uint8List inputImg = (await rootBundle.load("assets/test.jpg")).buffer.asUint8List()
```

It gives me a long array of over 800 ints for the same 5x4 image.

On testing it with two single-pixel images (one black and one white), a large section of the Uint8List seems to be repeating for each. I isolated the differing sections of the array and they do not correspond with the RGB values expected for the colors (I expected [0 0 0] and [255 255 255], but got something like 255, 0, 63, 250, 0, 255, 0 and 254, 254, 40, 3 for the two respectively)

I just need the RGB values in the image. Would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: try palette_generator, https://pub.dev/packages/palette_generator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images are normally [compressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression) when they're stored. Based on the file extension, I'm guessing you're using JPEG encoding. This means the data stored in the `assets/test.jpg` file is *not* an array of colors. That would be an inefficient use of data storage if everything were done that way. To get that array of colors, you need to *decode* the image. This can be done with the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package.

To do this, first add the package as a dependency by adding the following to the `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  image: ^3.0.4
```

You should follow the same method of obtaining the encoded image data. But you then need to decode it.

```dart
final Uint8List inputImg = (await rootBundle.load("assets/test.jpg")).buffer.asUint8List();
final decoder = JpegDecoder();
final decodedImg = decoder.decodeImage(inputImg);
final decodedBytes = decodedImg.getBytes(format: Format.rgb);
```

`decodedBytes` contains a single depth list of all your pixel values in RGB format. To get it into your desired format, just loop over the values and add them to a new list.

```dart
List<List<List<int>> imgArr = [];
for(int y = 0; y < decodedImage.height; y++) {
  imgArr.add([]);
  for(int x = 0; x < decodedImage.width; x++) {
    int red = decodedBytes[y*decodedImage.width*3 + x*3];
    int green = decodedBytes[y*decodedImage.width*3 + x*3 + 1];
    int blue = decodedBytes[y*decodedImage.width*3 + x*3 + 2];
    imgArr[y].add([red, green, blue]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, first add the package as a dependency by adding the following to the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
image: ^3.2.0
```

import image library to your file:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as im;
```

get brightness of image:

```
 int getBrightness(File file) {
    im.Image? image = im.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
    final data = image?.getBytes();
    var color= 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < data!.length; x += 4) {
    final int r = data[x];
    final int g = data[x + 1];
    final int b = data[x + 2];
    final int avg = ((r + g + b) / 3).floor();
    color += avg;
  }
  return (color/ (image!.width * image.height)).floor();
}
```

Check selected image is dark or light:

```
bool isImageDark(int brightness) {
  return brightness <= 127;
}
```

Use above method like this:

```
int brightness = getBrightness(file);
bool isDark= isImageDark(brightness);
```

Now you can change your icon color based on your background image